# Alternative approaches to search of negative roots of the equation $x^4-5x^3-4x^2-7x+4=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, alternative-proof, quartics

> How many **negative roots** does the following equation have?$$x^4-5x^3-4x^2-7x+4=0$$

#### My reasoning:

I rewrote the equation like: $$x^4-5x^3-4x^2-7x+4=0 \Rightarrow (x^2-2)^2 = 5x^3+7x$$

For any negative $x$, the outcome is never a negative term in the left member of the equation, and always a negative term in the right member of the equation. That's impossible, so the answer is that there are no negative roots for the original equation.

Does anyone see another way out?

Comment: You mean $(x^2 - 2)^2 = 5x^3 + 7x$?

Comment: O yeah, my bad. Thx.

Comment: Either way, you are correct, there are no negative roots.

Comment: Are yu familiar with [*Descartes' rule of signs*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes'_rule_of_signs)? Regards

Comment: I don't think so. I'm reading your link at the moment, though. What you got?

Comment: For any negative $x$ **tested**?  Can't you see immediately that $(x^2 - 2)^2 \ge 0$ for all real $x$, while $5 x^3 + 7 x < 0$ for all negative $x$?

Comment: Yeah, Robert, I can. I put it that way because the question bothers only about the negative roots.

Comment: @Sawyier I think he's worried about the word tested. It implies that you tested a couple and it worked every time, rather than the fact that it works in general

Comment: @Deven: You're right, I probably should've chosen a better word, even because I didn't really test anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to say explicitly that $\forall x < 0,\; x\neq -\sqrt{2}$, the left-hand side of the equation is positive (whatever the value of $x$ - save for $x = \pm \sqrt{2}$, in which case the LHS $= 0$), while the right hand side of the equation is negative $\forall x<0$, since $5x^3 + 7x = x(x^2 + 7)$, evaluates to the sign of $x$. This is impossible for any equation. Hence, there is no solution (i.e., root) $x$ such that $x \lt 0$.

Essentially, what you argued :-)

Certainly, there is no need to find the actual roots, as you observe.